# Style elements through JS efficiently - best practice

Tags: javascript, css, performance, ads

I am building a tool for creating banners at a quicker and more streamlined way, instead of creating each individually.

Doing so, I have a number of different formats (such as `300x300px`, `150x600px`, `970x250px`) and so forth.

The projects takes the container size as input, and should style and resize all elements based on the size.

Currently, it is very inefficient styling all properties individually.
An example is outlines below, however this list grows even longer for larger/more advanced banners with multiple elements.

### To the question

What is the "best practice" way of styling a lot of different elements programatically, rather than setting each property individually through the `style` property?

As file size is key, any 3rd party libraries are not an option.

### Current (inefficient) way of doing it

I am doing it this way to reduce file size, as I cannot have the styles for say 20 formats incorporated in the same file as it would grow too large.

```js
    let bannerSize = getBannerSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    let firstFrame = document.getElementById("#frame-1");
    let firstHeading = document.getElementById("#frame-1 h1");
    let firstSubHeading = document.getElementById("#frame-1 h2");
    let button = document.getElementById("#frame-1 button");
    let secondFrame = document.getElementById("#frame-2");
    
    if (bannerSize == 'square') {
        firstFrame.style.top = 0; 
        firstFrame.style.left = 0;
        firstFrame.style.width = '100%';
    
        firstHeading.style.top = 50 + 'px';
        firstHeading.style.left = 50 + 'px';
        firstHeading.style.fontSize = 28 + 'px';
    
        firstSubHeading.style.top = 120 + 'px';
        firstSubHeading.style.left = 50 + 'px';
        firstSubHeading.style.fontSize = 18 + 'px';
    
    } else if (bannerSize == 'portrait') {
        ...
    } else if (bannerSize == 'landscape') {
       ... 
    }
```

The output would then be as follows, where the same file can be used for multiple iframes and sizes:

[image]

Comment: **best practice** will only lead to an opinion-based answer. It depends on the architecture and requirements (such as maintenance, CMS, scalability, and accessibility...). The question is also far too broad for SO. For starters, I would start with a `for-loop` and remove all the repetitive code... Also instead of a writing multiple `else/if-statements` you could use a `switch-statement` which also is more performant

Comment: Once completed, it will be non-maintained, however editability in terms of changing styles, animations and so forth is key as the same setup will be used for other banners.

Comment: No connections to CMS, or simliar, will be done. The output is a single HTML file that will be used as-is for the banner formats

Comment: still far too rboad, start with an `array of objects` and a `for-loop` looping over that array of objects`. The objects should contain data such as height, width and the format or other details. If you still stuck, you can ask a more specific question about where you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

One one way to handle this would be through a generic function such as :

```
function styleElem(selector, style){
  (selector) ? selector.style.cssText = style : '';
  return
}
```

It will apply inline styles to your adslots (much more easy to read/use programmatically)
Usage :

```
var square = document.getElementById("#frame-1")
styleElem(square , "width:300px;height:300px;margin:50px");//apply your custom css styles

var skyscraper= document.getElementById("#frame-2")
styleElem(skyscraper, "width:150px;height:600px;margin:50px");
```